# What does the forward slash mean in the CSS font shorthand?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm seeing the following CSS declaration in a stylesheet:

```css
font: 12px/18px ...
```

What does the `12px/18px` part mean exactly?

Comment: It was incorrect to close this as too localized. The question is simple, and so is the answer, but it is clearly something that people ask often, and has a good answer.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

`12px` is the font size, `18px` is the line height.

The syntax is based on typographical notation for specifying the respective sizes, and is only applicable to the `font` shorthand property. In other words, the above declaration simply expands to the following:

```css
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
```

As always, if you set the line height to a relative value (e.g. percentage or ems), it's calculated relative to the font size.

[W3C CSS2.1 `font` property reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font)
[W3C CSS3 Fonts Module `font` property reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-prop) (the syntax carries over from CSS2.1)

Answer (score 66):

It's equivalent to:

```css
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
```