# What does 12px/13px do in css font declarations?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this CSS shorthand font syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080265/what-does-this-css-shorthand-font-syntax-mean)

I saw many people doing that:

```
body {
font: bold 12px/13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

What is this 12px/13px for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

12px is the font size and 13px the line height.

Example of declaring all font properties in a one liner [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_font).

---

*All this being said, I'll just add that this is a pretty unusual way of writing it and I wouldn't recommend it since it might confuse most developers.*

Comment: Learning alternative syntaxes in languages that I've been supposedly mastering for years makes me feel really ashamed :-)

Answer (score 2):

The 12px is the height of the font in pixels.  The 13px is the height of the line in pixels.

Answer (score 2):

You might see something like

```
body { font:13px/1.231 sans-serif; *font-size:small; }
```

Notice there is no "px" after 1.231 and the line height in this case will be 123.1% of the text size. This is used to unify native line-heights that might otherwise be larger or smaller that you'd want them.