# what does this font resize mean?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this CSS do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080265/what-does-this-css-do)

what does this font resize code in css mean exactly ??

```
font:12px/170% Verdana,sans-serif
```

Answer (score 0):

font is a short hand for a lot of font related settings, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font

In your Example: `font:<font-size>/<line-height> <font-family>`

So the font-size is 12px and the line height are 170% of that (20.4px).