# A couple of CSS questions regarding robot-or-not.com code

Tags: css, font-size

```
  body {
    background: #E2E2E2 url("/-/img/bg.jpg") repeat -20% -146px;
    color: #45445d;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    font: normal 100%/1.5 Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

This is a code snippet from [robot-or-not.com](http://robot-or-not.com/) ...featured in an article called ..Responsive Webdesign. I have two questions about the CSS in the article.

- If I want to use em's across a site I
  understand that I need a base font
  size and then work out the em by
  TARGET SIZE / BASE SIZE = EM. Do I
  need then to set the base font size
  in "PX" in the body first and in the
  code above what does font: 100%/1.5
  mean?
- My second question is about the
  background property.. what does
  repeat "-20% -146px;"  this mean/do?
  I know about repeat:no-repeat and
  repeat-y, repeat-x but have never
  used % or PX for this..

Comment: For `font: 100%/1.5`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080265/what-does-this-css-do/4080268#4080268

Comment: thanks for the link.. I'm more interested in what size is 100%? an 1.5em? of what? 

good link though, I'm not so good at the short hand..

Comment: The percentage relates to the default font size specified in your web client I believe: it's not an absolute (for example, many browsers typically set your default font size to 16px).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't **need** a "base size". The default size for fonts is configured by the user in his/her browser. This is what the browser then uses for 1em (or 100%).

You can define your own "base size" in the body (`body { font-size: 12px }`) and then go ahead and use `em`s (or `%`) for other font-sizes, such as `h1 { font-size: 1.5em }` instead of `h1 { font-size: 18px }` (12px * 1.5 = 18px). This has the "advantage" for you as the developer that if you choose to change your "base size", then all other font-sizes (or other `em` based values) will scale accordingly.

However by setting such a pixel-based base size, you override the users configured (and thus probably preferred) font-size with your (the designers) choice. Many designers do this, because they believe their pixel-perfect design must not be disturbed by the users preferences. Whether you need this or let the user choose is your decision.

`100%/1.5` is part of the [`font` shorthand property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-prop) and is the abbreviation for setting `font-size: 100%` and `line-height: 1.5`.

[`background`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background) is also a short hand property and `background: #E2E2E2 url("/-/img/bg.jpg") repeat -20% -146px;` extends to:

```
background-color: #E2E2E2;
background-image: url("/-/img/bg.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: -20% -146px;
```

`background-position: -20% -146px` means that the top left corner of the background image isn't positioned at the top left corner of its element, but it is pushed 20% of the width of its element to the left and 146 pixels up.

Comment: Even though this was a great answer reading css from apple.com still bugs me.. 
[link](http://images.apple.com/global/styles/base.css)
The body base size is 12px/18px line-height.. yet when I read the Heading tags - H3 is set as EM and the rest as PX... why not just make them all ems? there must be a reason for this choice..

Comment: @smoop: The simplest answer is: The developer simply didn't care or several developers worked on it with different views on the matter.