# Replace  Comma(,) with Dot(.) RegEx php

Tags: php, regex

i am trying this code but i get this error: `No ending delimiter '/' found`

```
$form = " 2000,50";
$salary = preg_replace('/',', '.'/', $form); // No ending delimiter '/' found 
echo $salary;
```

I am not sure about the regex validation.

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Regex is overkill for replacing just a single character. Why not just do this instead?

```
str_replace(',', '.', $form);
```

Comment: Indeed. Why use a power drill with 12 thousand attachments when a screw driver suffices?

Comment: @Midas: It seems to be a trend for basic answers to receive disproportionate amounts of upvotes on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080265/what-does-this-css-do/4080268#4080268 and most of my top answers are examples.

Comment: In this instance, str_replace() performs a little more than 4 times faster than preg_replace(), so str_replace() is clearly the best choice.

Answer (score 6):

```
$salary = preg_replace('/,/', '.', $form);
```

But yeah, you don't really want to match a *pattern* but a string which is *constant*, so simply use `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use

```
str_replace(',','.',$form);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your parameters -- I'm not sure what's supposed to be in the string and what isn't. But for preg_replace, the search pattern should be a string, and with the string also begin and end with a delimiter (typically '/'). I think it's redudant to need slashes round the search string when it's already inside a string, but that's how it works.

The second parameter should be a string containing the full stop and nothing else. This gives:

$salary = preg_replace( '/,/' , '.' , $form);

Other people are correct that str_replace will be fine for turning one character into another, but if the replacement you want gets more complicated preg_replace will be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

The '/' in your string is used as a start-of-regex delimiter so you need to escape it. The correct line should read:

```
$salary = preg_replace('\\/',', '.'/', $form);
```

I'm also curious why the second param is ', ' . '/' rather than ', /'.

EDIT

Ahh I see now, the line should read:

```
$salary = preg_replace( '/,/', '.', $form);
```

I was confused because the first comma in your example should be a '.' to concat the string.