# What is the CSS font shorthand property composed of?

Tags: css

```
font:100 1.1em/37px Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
```

What does the `100` mean? `font-weight`? What does the `1.1em` mean? `line-height`? And `37px`? `font-size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right on the font weight, but `1.1em/37px` means the font size is 1.1 ems and the line height is 37 pixels, not the other way around.

[W3C CSS2.1 `font` property reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font)

See also: [What does this CSS font shorthand syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080265/what-does-this-css-shorthand-font-syntax-mean/4080268#4080268)

Comment: Can I also specify the font-size in px? and is beeter to write it this way in one line as..if I will write it in more lines?

Comment: @Uffo: Yes, you can use any CSS unit. You can either use the shorthand property or specify each part separately - use whichever you think will help you understand the code easier.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a cool font shorthand cheat sheet which can be found [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/).

[image]

So in your example, 100 is the font-weight, 1.1em is the font-size, and 37px is the line-height.

Answer (score 0):

Its short hand.

http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/font/#font

Basically its setting the font size, then family.

Comment: Not just the size and the family.