# What does this font tag syntax mean?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this CSS shorthand font syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080265/what-does-this-css-shorthand-font-syntax-mean)

I was looking at some styles and I didn't know what the syntax of this font tag meant?

```
font: 13px/80px
```

Is this a min/max option for font size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `13px` sets the `font-size` property.  The `80px` sets the `line-height` property.

[CSS Fonts Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-prop)

Comment: Why not cite the completed CSS2.1 specification instead of the CSS3 draft?

Comment: Because google *site:w3.org css font* listed that first.

Comment: @Nightfirecat: I'm going to have to blame it on everyone eagerly climbing aboard the HTML5/CSS3 bandwagon before they even reinforced its chassis.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'll agree wholeheartedly with you there.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not min/max. `13px` is the font size and `80px` is the line height to be considered.