# Specifying two sizes in CSS font property?

Tags: css, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this CSS shorthand font syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080265/what-does-this-css-shorthand-font-syntax-mean)

Sometimes the font is specified using two values, for example

```
font: 14px/60px
```

Why are two values specified? When the 60px will be used? Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The 60px is the line-height. It's a shorthand for:

```
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 60px;
```

Comment: Can't seem to declare font: 14px/60px; is there a way to declare both in a single line like that?

Comment: @raison It won't work without adding the font-face after `14px/60px` so try `font: 14px/60px Arial`

Answer (score 6):

60px will be the line-height value

see http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5342/css-font-shorthand-rule/

Answer (score 5):

The first value give the font size, the second the line height.