# / (forward slash) in css style declarations

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this CSS font shorthand syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080265/what-does-this-css-font-shorthand-syntax-mean)

Recently while checking apple's website's styling, I came across this CSS rule declaration which I could not understand:

```
body {
   font: 12px/18px "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
```

I could not understand, and thus wanted to know that how does the forward slash in `font: 12px/18px` actually work?

Comment: @SvenBieder What would you suggest to google? I googled 'forward slash in css' and this question was first on google.

Comment: @EricFrancis While the question was clearly asked and answered before, it is expressed more clearly here. Webnet's earlier question is not badly written. It is narrowly written, and so omits several terms and phrases that have allowed this question to rank more highly--or at all--in search results. A Google search circa 2017 confirms that we are better off with Peeyush having asked this question.

Comment: It's alright, that's how SO's system is designed. They don't close off duplicates for exactly this reason, so that different ways in which the same question can be asked can point to the correct answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It simply means `font-size` and `line-height`

```
font: 12px/18px /*12px font-size and 18px line-height*/
```

That's a short-hand notation...There are many more in CSS which you can use, for example

```
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-left: 40px;
```

Can be simply written as

```
margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px
         ^----^----^----^
       Top/Right/Bottom/Left
```

Or say for example this

```
border-width: 1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color: #ff0000;
```

Can be written as

```
border: 1px solid #f0000;
```

Here's a cool [**list**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) of CSS shorthand.

Comment: Any specification?

Comment: @КонстантинВан Check [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#Syntax) point here

Answer (score 1):

It's shorthand for `font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px`.

Answer (score 0):

Its a short cut for setting 2 css properties and does the same as the following:

```
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
```