# Difference between space and comma -- CSS property values(not in selector)

Tags: css

What's the difference of space and comma in CSS property value(not for selector)?

```
font:bold 60px helvetical, arial, sans-serif;
```

I just had a test, it has different effect when change comma to space or vice versa in above style, so I want to know when to use space/comma?

Comment: Spaces separate the components of the property, comman separates the values of one property. Your example can be written as: `font-weight: bold; font-size: 60px; font-family: helvetical, arial, sans-serif;`. Check this answer for more details: [When a CSS property can have multiple values, are those values always separated by whitespaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392420)

Comment: That depends on the specific syntax of the specific property. There's no *general* answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When a CSS property can have multiple values, are those values always separated by whitespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392420/when-a-css-property-can-have-multiple-values-are-those-values-always-separated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Space:**

Each value make different function. For example:

```
font: bold 60px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
```

***bold*** = `font-weight: bold;`

***60px*** = `font-size: 60px;`

`bold` do the weight and `60px` do the size, these two are different from each other.

**Comma:**

***helvetica, arial, sans-serif*** = `font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;`

Values in comma do the same function. They all change `font-family`.
In this case:

If `helvetica` it's not supported then loads `arial`, if `arial` it's not supported then loads `sans-serif`.

**Using fonts with two words:**

If you use fonts that contains two words and have **spaces** like `Roboto Slab`.

For these fonts you have to put them on double quotes `"roboto slab"`.

Example: `font: bold 60px "roboto slab", arial, sans-serif;`