# Order of font and line-height in a rule set

Tags: html, css

I didn't think the order of CSS within a rule set mattered, as long as there weren't implicitly duplicate rules (such as `border` and `border-top`).

In fact, many CSS Style Guides recommend an arbitrary order such as "By group" or "Alphabetically."

However, the order of `font` and `line-height` within a rule set can make a big difference:

```css
div {border: 1px solid gray; float: left;}
#D1 {font: 20px arial; line-height: 3;}
#D2 {line-height: 3; font: 20px arial;}
```

```html
<div id="D1">This is a test</div>
<div id="D2">This is a test</div>
```

A unitless line-height should be a multiplier of the font size.

But why does the `font` rule have to precede the `line-height` rule for this to happen?

Comment: Because `font` is shorthand for multiple properties, which **include** line-height. See [**font @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font).

Comment: This question is kinda sorta the antithesis of [What does this CSS font shorthand syntax mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080265/what-does-this-css-font-shorthand-syntax-mean), which features a font shorthand that includes line-height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite its name, `line-height` is actually part of the [`font` shorthand](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-shorthand). The shorthand declaration sets `line-height` to its initial value of `normal`, which overrides your previous `line-height` declaration.

To this end, you can incorporate `line-height` into the shorthand, as shown below with the addition of a `#D3` element:

```css
div {border: 1px solid gray; float: left;}
#D1 {font: 20px arial; line-height: 3;}
#D2 {line-height: 3; font: 20px arial;}
#D3 {font: 20px/3 arial;}
```

```html
<div id="D1">This is a test</div>
<div id="D2">This is a test</div>
<div id="D3">This is a test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Learned something new.  Will accept when I can.